# Integral with the delta function: How to get this limit?

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

Consider $\Psi_{xx}+(\lambda-u(x))\Psi=0$ and $u(x)=-U_0\delta(x)$, where $U_0$ is a constant and $\delta(x)$ is Dirac's delta function.

Integrating the equation from $-\varepsilon$ to $+\varepsilon$, one gets
$$
[\Psi_x]_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon=\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon (\lambda+U_0\delta(x))\Psi\, dx.
$$

Now it is said that, if $\varepsilon\to 0$, one gets
$$
[\Psi_x]=-U_0\Psi(0),\tag{*}
$$
where $[\cdot]$ denotes the change in $\Psi_x$, provided $\Psi$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Can someone explain to me how we get $(*)$? I do not see it.
In particular, where does the (assumed) continuity of $\Psi$ at $x=0$ come into play?

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate an integral with a dirac delta function in the integrand?

Comment: Do you suggest $$\int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon}(\lambda + U_0\delta(x))\Psi\, dx=\int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon}\lambda\Psi\, dx+\underbrace{\int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon}U_0\delta(x)\Psi\, dx}_{=U_0\Psi(0)}$$ and the first integral on the right-hand side tends to $0$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$ only if $\Psi$ is continuous in $x=0$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Suppose $\Psi$ is **not** continuous at $x=0$. Why does the integral then not vanish as $\varepsilon\to 0$?

Comment: Two things: (1) if $\Psi$ is continuous on $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$, then it attains a maximum $M$ on that interval, and the integral on that interval is $\le 2M\epsilon$, but if it isn't continuous, then it's possible $\lim_{x\to 0}\Psi(x)=\infty$ and the integral isn't even defined (2) $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}f(x)\delta(x)=f(0)$ if $f$ is continuous at 0; otherwise evaluating that, if possible, requires more advanced analysis.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the fourier transform wrt $x$:
$$\mathcal{F}[\varphi(x,t)]\{\omega\}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi e^{-j\omega x}\,dx=\hat{\varphi}(\omega,t)$$
and assume that:
$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\varphi=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\varphi_x=0$$
you arrive at the equation:
$$(\lambda-\omega^2)\hat{\varphi}+U_0\varphi(0,t)=0$$
then you can use the inverse fourier transform and boundary conditions for $\varphi$.